# Insert json data to existing remote server in corona

Tags: json, coronasdk

How to post  data  to my own server. I can fetch data from it but can't  add data .Code for fetch is below:

```
local function networkListener( event )
 if ( event.isError ) then
   print( "Network error!")
 else
   local  json=event.response 

   local length=string.len(json)
   json=string.sub(json, 50, (length-1));

   jsonTable=JSON.encode(json)
   local t = jsonTable
   print(jsonTable)
   -- Go through the array in a loop
   for key in pairs(t) do
    -- Here you can do whatever you like with the values
    print(t[key]["AuthorID"])
    print(t[key]["AuthorName"])
    --print(t[key]["returnvalue3"])
   end
  end
end
local  remoteFeed="http://www.xtremeesolutions.com/xesapps/webservice/readauthors.php"
network.request(remoteFeed, "GET", networkListener)
--And trying code to post data is 

local function postData(e)
  if (e.isError)then
    print("Error ");
  else
    print("Error ".. e.response);
  end
 end

local params = {

            body = query
    }
network.request(remoteFeed, "POST",postData,params))
```

Above code not giving any error  but also not inserting values.Please suggest me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **"POST"** instead of "GET", see the code below:

```
...
local  remoteFeed="http://www.xtremeesolutions.com/xesapps/webservice/readauthors.php"
network.request(remoteFeed, "POST", networkListener, params)
```

Maybe you should also check this link http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html at section: **HTTP POST with custom headers**

**EDITED**

the loop for handle post value should be:

```
if ( event.isError ) then
   print( "Network error!")
else
    ...
    for key in pairs(t) do
        postData = t[key]["AuthorID"] .. "=" .. t[key]["AuthorName"] 
    end
    local params = {}
    params.body = postData

    local remoteFeed="http://www.xtremeesolutions.com/xesapps/webservice/readauthors.php"
    network.request(remoteFeed, "POST", networkListener, params)
end
```

those lines should be togather in else scope.

Comment: I tried this code:                                                local function networkListener( event )
if ( event.isError ) then
                print( "Network error!")
        else
                print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
        end
end                                                                    network.request("http://www.xtremeesolutions.com/xesapps/webservice/readauthors.php", "POST",networkListener). But values not added

Comment: Sorry, you should also send the params in request, I will edit in my answer.

Comment: network.request("xtremeesolutions.com/xesapps/webservice/readauthors.php", "POST",networkListener,params) but not yet inserted

Comment: Yes, that's right. And you have to design how to manage the json values you got to set in params.